# VueJS - Host in a subdirectory - working sample?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Hi guys I was wondering if anyone has a working sample of hosting a vue js application in a subdirectory rather than the root?

I have seen bits and pieces of advice here and elsehwhere on the setup but i have yet to see an actual working sample anywhere end to end.

Answer (score 0):

In you `vue.config.js` you can add a `publicPath` with the path you want to host your project

> This only works if you've use the vue cli

For example:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/admin',
};
```

You can also open the vue cli documentation:

> The base URL your application bundle will be deployed at (known as baseUrl before Vue CLI 3.3). This is the equivalent of webpack's output.publicPath, but Vue CLI also needs this value for other purposes, so you should always use publicPath instead of modifying webpack output.publicPath.

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Comment: i have read these tips before and they do not work for me.   This is why asked for a working sample.  Vuerouter constructor also needs a base as well.  This is the challenge I am having is wherever I go I get one puzzle piece only.  I need to see an actual working sample, not just a quick tip.

Comment: Did you create your project using the vue cli?
If you do adding the file i included in my answer should do the trick.

If you didn't perhaps it's the best to create a project via the vuecli then you can test this.